# Where does the energy needed for a $W$ Boson come from?

Tags: particle-physics, energy-conservation, standard-model

The $W$ boson is an 80 GeV particle who's life is very very very short ($3\times 10^{-25}$ seconds).
An Down quark emits a $W^-$ and becomes an Up quark.  the $W^-$ then breaks down into an anti-neutrino and an electron.

It would be like me having a 1 ton car, opening the passenger door and emitting 80 tons of car parts and then having a 1500 pound car.

But where does that 80 GeV come from?  One explanation in another similar question here on the Exchange states that it is caused by an excitation of a quantum field. But what is the mechanism for this? How does the decay of the Down quark excite this field?

Comment: Because the internal line corresponding to the $W$ boson in the Feynman diagram you describe is not a real $W$ boson, it is a [virtual particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_particle)

Comment: To add on to @JeanbaptisteRoux's comment, in order to create a real $W$ (as opposed to a virtual one), you would need the quarks (or whatever incoming particles) to have significant kinetic energy in order to conserve energy, which is why we build particle accelerators. However, indeed, for neutron decay the $W$ boson is virtual.

Comment: Does the virtual particle have mass?  If so what is that mass>

Answer (score 1):

The 80GeV W boson has been observed in collider experiments , The first researchers got the Nobel prize for the [discovery:](https://cds.cern.ch/record/2103277/files/9789814644150_0006.pdf?subformat=pdfa&version=1),and its existence is consistent with the electroweak theory. The energy to get at that mass is provided by the very energetic beams.The W boson has many decay channels available.

> [W bosons can decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W_and_Z_bosons#W_bosons_2) to a lepton and antilepton (one of them charged and another neutral)[d] or to a quark and antiquark of opposing types.

True for W Bosons on mass shell, as the ones measured in the link given.

For real on mass shell W's the energy is in the mass, which they acquired when created in the interaction of the proton and antiproton (in the link).

If you are confusing the [virtual](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html) off mass shell W's used as place holders for quantum number exchanges in Feynman diagrams,  virtual Ws have a variable mass, depending on the limits of the integration of the specific diagram, and they are called W in order to keep count of the quantum  numbers in the interaction, not of energy and momentum which are all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

The W boson has a mass $M_W=80.379(12)\,{\rm GeV/c^2}$. It also has a width $\Gamma=2.085(42)\,{\rm GeV/c^2}$. That means if you were to make real W's in an electron-anti-neutrino collider, they'd have a mass distribution:

$$f(E) \propto \frac{1}{(E^2-M_W^2)^2+M_W^2\Gamma^2}$$

aka, the Breit-Wigner distribution, aka the Cauchy distribution (which famously has an undefined variance). That means there is probability to make a real W with a mass $m_e$, it's just small....which is why the weak force is weak until $E$ is on the order of $M_W$.

Of course, the W in beta decay is virtual, which leads to some subtleties.
Regarding "the d-quark emits a W and then...".... this is the language of old fashioned (time-ordered) perturbation theory (OFPT). In that, momentum is conserved and energy is not, so you can violate energy conservation per the uncertainty principle.

The idea that $m_d \ll M_W$ would prohibit it is totally inapplicable, as it is only half the story in OFPT. There is another diagram in which a $W^+$ and the $e^-$ and $\bar{\nu}_e$ spontaneously form in the vacuum with the W the being absorbed by the $d$ quark.

In Lorentz covariant field theory, there is but one Feynman diagram in which momentum and energy are conserved at all vertices, but:

$$ E^2_W - p^2_W \ne M^2_W $$

which is why virtual particles are said to be "off their mass shell", or just "off-shell". Note that the $W$ momentum is space-like, that is $M^2_W \lt 0$, so there is no time-ordering to the vertices...that is a frame dependent choice, and the W is just "exchanged", and it could be a $W^-$ or a $W^+$.

The moral of the story is: don't treat virtual particles as real particles. It's a common pitfall. There's an initial state and a final state, and the  fields take all possible configurations that  conserve 4-momentum, charge, etc to get between them. Virtual particles are way to organize those configurations in a why that gives us some insight into the process (and they allow theorist to calculate the amplitude, approximately).